# C++ Return a local or temp variable

Tags: c++, local, temp

Hi guys some problem here:

here is my overloaded operator :

```
const double & Waz::operator()(int i,int j) const
{
return ((WazImpl const)(*p))(i,j);
}
```

Where in Waz class I have : WazImpl* p; and in the class WazImpl I have an operator ()

The warning is :
Warning C4172 returning address of local variable or temporary

As far as I understand I'm returning a temp variable which is destroyed somewhere else what can I do to fix it?

Thanks!

Comment: what is the implementation of `WasImp::operator()(int,int)`?

Comment: Avoid C-cast. (and I think it should be `(WazImpl const&)(*p)` with reference)

Comment: BTW, returning just a `double` seems sufficient.

Answer (score 3):

If you dissect the function you can see that it is equivalent to the following:

```
const double& Waz::operator()(int i, int j) const {
    // Cast pointer to callable.
    const WazImpl& wi = static_cast<const WazImpl>(*p);

    // Get result of calling callable.
    double d = wi(i, j);

    // Return REFERENCE to local object.
    return d;
} // All local objects is destroyed and references to them become dangling.
```

So, you indeed get a dangling reference when calling your `Waz::operator`.

One solution is to return by *value* which will return a *copy* of the result. Also don't return by `const value` as it makes little sense.

```
double Waz::operator()(int i, int j) const;
```

Answer (score 1):

You have two possibilities. The first one is to return simply `double` instead of the reference `const double &`

```
double Waz::operator()(int i,int j) const
{
   return ((WazImpl const)(*p))(i,j);
}
```

The second one is to return the reference to the original value provided that the called operator also returns const reference to double

```
const double & Waz::operator()(int i,int j) const
{
   const double &rd = (WazImpl const)(*p))(i,j );

   return rd;
}
```

Here is a simple example that demonstrates the second approach

```
#include <iostream>

struct A
{
    int & operator ()(){ return a; }
    int a = 10;
};

struct B : A
{
    int & operator ()()
    {
        int &ri = A::operator ()();
        return ri;
    }
};

int main() 
{
    B b;

    b() = 20;

    std::cout << b.a << std::endl;


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your second option does not change anything. If `(WazImpl const)(*p))(i,j)` returns a temporary value then `Waz::operator()` still return a reference to a temporary.

Comment: @log0 I wrote that provided that the called operator also returns const reference.

Comment: Ok I see but it should be clear that your second "option" actually does the same thing as the code in the question. I think we agree that the problem is in the implementation of `WazImpl`.

Comment: @log0 You are mistaken. It is not the same.

Comment: Of course I may be wrong but for me it is the same. If the OP has a warning it means that `WazImpl::operator()` returns a `double`. Then your code adds an intermediate reference that can be optimized away but I don't think it really changes what is happening. Am I missing something ?

Comment: @log0 OP gets warning because it returns reference to a temporary object. It is a big difference. And optimization has nothing common with C++ symantics. Optimization does not change semantics

Comment: Yes we agree the semantic is the same. If you remove `rd` in your example it may remove the warning on some compilers but it does not fix the problem at all. You are still returning a reference to a temporary.

Comment: @log0 Why is a reference to temporary object is returned if the called operator returns a reference?

Comment: The warning is here in the first place because `(WazImpl const)(*p))(i,j)` is a temporary. So if you assign it to `rd` you have a ref to a temporary. if you return `rd`it does not change anything, it is still a reference to a temporary. Does what I say makes sense ?

Comment: @log0 I think that when this expression is placed in the return statement then lvalue to rvalue conversion is perfotmed.

Answer (score 0):

You should show us the implementation of WazImpl but it seems that `WazImpl::operator() const` returns a `double`.

It means that `((WazImpl const)(*p))(i,j)` returns a temporary (it exists only in the scope of Waz::operator()).
As `Waz::operator()` returns a  `double &`, you are indeed returning a reference to a temporary.

Either you are returning a temporary value that just got computed in `WazImpl::operator()` then you should return a `double` in `Waz::operator()` either you are really returning a reference to an existing double in `WazImpl` and you should fix the signature of `WazImpl::operator() const` so that it returns a `const double&`.